# Write to standard error in powershell fails jenkins job?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

The documentation page of [Microsoft Powershell support for Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/) (Which is part of the Processes and Nodes plugin, not the powershell plugin!!) says that the following:

```
node {
    def stdout = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
        ...
      Write-Error 'Something terrible has happened!'
        ...
   ''')
  }
```

Will fail the job, since:

> The failure in this example is due to the PowerShell error stream being non-empty, which therefore caused the step to result in a non-zero exit status.

Incidentally, this is not accurate since in order for the job to fail you have to add

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

However, I tried the following:

```
 powershell script: '''
                  $ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
                  cmd.exe /c "echo hello 1>&2"
                  
                '''
```

and the output:

```
[Pipeline] powershell
powershell.exe : cmd.exe : hello 
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Powershell\Stderror@tmp\durable-3a4c71ca\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (cmd.exe : hello :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Powershell\Stderror@tmp\durable-3a4c71ca\powershellScript.ps1:2 char:19
+                   cmd.exe /c "echo hello 1>&2" 2>&1
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (hello :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So although there is a write to the error stream, the job doesn't fail, which is not exactly what's noted in the docs.

Comment: I think what you meant to try is `cmd.exe /c "echo hello" 2>&1`.